# Is it possible to capture console output from beforebuild/afterbuild targets and display as Visual Studio output?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I've created both a pre-processor and a post-build program that I run as part of my Visual Studio builds, by specifying them via the BeforeBuild and AfterBuild MSBuild targets. They write error messages to console and to a log file.

Is there any way I could get Visual Studio to capture this output and show it in the Output window?

The projects being built are C# projects (.csproj), but I'm guessing this isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: If your programs print to console the messages should appear at the output window (just tested that with VS2012). Could you please post your AfterBuild target, visual studio output and version?

Comment: @MarcosBrigante: Good grief, yes, you're right. I was sure my preprocessor and post-build programs were writing to both console and to log file, but now I can see that at some time for some crazy reason I had commented-out the writing to the console. Damn. Thank you very much for making me double-check. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your programs print to console the messages should appear at the output window.